# Docker Container Based on Non Existing Image?

Tags: ssh, docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

In the process of building a better understanding of SSH and Docker (I know that there are ways around running SSH in a container). I reviewed this container [danielguerra/alpine-sshd](https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/alpine-sshd/).

The first command in the usage instructions utilizes this image:
[danielguerra/ssh-container](https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/ssh-container/).

Note that I'm specifically asking about this command that references the `ssh-container` image:

```
 docker create -v /root/.ssh --name ssh-container danielguerra/ssh-container /bin/true
```

However that repository is empty.  There is no `Dockerfile` present.  So I'm curious what image the container ends up being based on then?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 2):

You refer to [danielguerra/alpine-sshd](https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/alpine-sshd/) which makes reference to `Source Repository` of [danielguerra69/alpine-sshd](https://github.com/danielguerra69/alpine-sshd/blob/master/Dockerfile) which lists a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/danielguerra69/alpine-sshd/blob/master/Dockerfile) with a base image of

```
FROM alpine:edge
```

for completeness here is entire Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:edge
MAINTAINER Daniel Guerra <daniel.guerra69@gmail.com>

RUN apk add --update openssh

RUN ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa

RUN sed -i "s/UsePrivilegeSeparation.*/UsePrivilegeSeparation no/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && sed -i "s/UsePAM.*/UsePAM no/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && sed -i "s/PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config && sed -i "s/#AuthorizedKeysFile/AuthorizedKeysFile/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

*UPDATE*

Answer to your comment ... create an empty dir and put above Dockerfile into that dir ... then cd into that dir issue a command similar to

```
docker build --tag ${YOUR_DOCKERHUB_ID}/${THIS_IMAGENAME} .
```

specifically Daniel evidently used this command

```
docker build --tag danielguerra/ssh-container .
```

Notice the trailing period ( . ) in above ... it denotes directory of Dockerfile ... then to make that image visible to the world Daniel pushed this spanking new image to Docker Hub using

```
docker login # only necessary once to authenticate your DockerHub Id
docker push danielguerra/ssh-container
```

Comment: Hi - Would you also happen to know what image the first command in the usage instructions that references the `danielguerra/ssh-container` uses.  The docker repository for that image is empty...so it seems like the container is constructed based on some sort of default in docker....?

Comment: Hi - I'm still confused - the https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/ssh-container/ link does not reference a Dockerfile at all ... With the instructions you have in answer we would get at least a Dockerfile right?

Comment: When people simply do a docker push of their image to DockerHub it lands with no README or any doc unless they add this afterward ... as happened with image danielguerra/ssh-container  ... try this yourself ... create image using "docker build --tag OlehubId/aabbcc .  " ...   followed by docker push OlehubId/aabbcc   ... after push examine your DockerHub entry ... it'll be barren as Daniel's ... so Yes Daniel does supply a Dockerfile

Comment: Is there a way to see the Dockerfile that he pushed to this repository: https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/ssh-container/  ?

Comment: For example this repository https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/alpine-sshd/ has a `Dockerfile` tab that I can look at to see the `Dockefile` but this repository does not: https://hub.docker.com/r/danielguerra/ssh-container/

Comment: Does docker hub default to not showing the `Dockerfile` when no README is present?